# How do I pause in League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends

A few days ago my internet started to bug arond when I was playing LoL, causing disconnects etc.

Now since I wanna participate in a small online tournament I wanted to know how to use the Pause function, so me or another player can pause the game when someone is disconnected.

Also: Can you only pause games in tournament mode or in different modes aswell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can only pause in Custom Games using Tournament Draft mode using the `/pause` chat command. You can then unpause the game using `/unpause` or `/resume`. Here's a quote from the [official competitive site](http://competitive.na.leagueoflegends.com/article/tournament-code-and-custom-game-pause-features):

> This feature is only available in **Tournament Draft** Custom Games. The commands to use the pause feature are, as you might have guessed, **/pause** and **/unpause**.

Comment: To add to this, there is a global pool of 30 minutes for the pause. Upon resumption, there will be a 5 second period to wait for players to get ready. The game can be resumed by any player on either team, and while paused, the camera cannot be moved.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pause games, unless it's a custom game. 
You can pause Tournament Draft games, by simply typing `/pause` in chat and unpause it by typing `/unpause` in chat.

Good luck mate.