# What are all the in-game chat commands available in LoL?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've heard that there are some commands far from the ones shown in `/help` list.

Which are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `/help` or `/?` lists most commands
- `/all` sends a message to all chat
- `/whisper` or `/w` or `/msg` sends a private message to a friend
- `/r` replies to last PM
- `/mute` mute the specified player*
- `/ignore` add a player to your pvp.net ignore list*
- `/surrender` or `/ff` vote to surrender
- `/nosurrender` of `/noff` vote against surrendering
- `/pause` or `/p` [pause a tournament match](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/153191/how-do-i-pause-in-league-of-legends)
- `/unpause` or `/resume` resume a paused game
- `/joke` or `/j` your champ tells a joke
- `/taunt` or `/t` your champ taunts
- `/dance` or `/d` your champ dances
- `/laugh` or `/l` your champ laughs
- `/note` or `/n` writes a note to `MyNotes.txt`, which can be found in `RADS\solutions\lol_game_client_sln\releases\<current release>`

* you can use @-prefix to use champion name, `/mute @Heimerdinger` for example.

The ones missing from `/help` that are on this list are `/mute`, `/ignore`, `/pause` and `/unpause` (and their aliases).

I cross checked a few lists and my memory and then tested them in-game. It's probably still missing some forgotten or hard-to-find commands.

Comment: /n works for /note as well